# VBScript output: formatting to a column (data can vary in length)

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I would like to have a batch file that will query for a list of services (DisplayName,State,StartMode), but have them output into a nicely formatted when looking at it in a txt file.

Here's what I have to dump it to a .csv file, but I want to have it in a txt file that will have other info and won't be feasible to use Excel (normally using notepad to open this file and want to keep it this way).

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colListOfServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Service WHERE DisplayName LIKE 'CommVault%'")
wscript.echo chr(34) & "Service Name" & chr(34) & "," & chr(34) & "Status" & chr(34) & "," & chr(34) & "Start Mode" & chr(34)
For Each objService in colListOfServices
    wscript.echo chr(34) & objService.DisplayName & chr(34) & "," & chr(34) & objService.State & chr(34) & "," & chr(34) & objService.StartMode & chr(34)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this MyServiceViewer.hta.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
BODY        {font-size :100%;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: black;
        background:URL(images/watermark.gif);background-color: white;
        margin-top:0; margin-left:0pt; margin-right:0pt ; text-align:Justify}
P       {margin-left:40pt;margin-right:10pt}
TABLE       {font-size: 90%; text-align:left; margin-left:40pt;margin-right:10pt;background-color:lavender;width:90%}
THEAD       {color: white;font-weight:bold;background-color:darkblue; margin-left:40pt;margin-right:10pt}
TD      {Vertical-Align:Top;padding:3px}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:333C7BC4-460F-11D0-BC04-0080C7055A83"
    ID=dsoMacro5 WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0>
    <PARAM NAME="DataURL" VALUE="Services.txt">
    <PARAM NAME="UseHeader" Value="True">
    <PARAM NAME="FieldDelim" VALUE=",">
    <PARAM NAME="Sort"  Value="Service Name">
</OBJECT>
<h3>My Services Database</h3>
<h4>Select a button to filter list</h4>
<p>To search for a word in the Title field use <i>* word *</i>. To search for the first word in a field use <i>Word *</i> or the last word use <i>* word</i>. To search for a string within a word or word use <i>*partialword*</i>. Searches are case sensitive.</i></p>
<p><INPUT Name=tb1 TYPE=Text Value=""> <INPUT ID=cmdNavFirst TYPE=BUTTON VALUE="     Search     " onclick="dsoMacro5.object.filter='Service Name=' + tb1.value;dsoMacro5.reset()"></p>
<p><INPUT ID=cmdNavFirst TYPE=BUTTON VALUE="   Sort Status   " onclick="dsoMacro5.object.sort='Status';dsoMacro5.reset()"></p>
<hr class="body">
<TABLE ID=tblMacro2 DATASRC=#dsoMacro5 OnRowEnter=Alert(tblMacro2.row)>
<THEAD>
<TR>
<TD WIDTH="60%"><b>Service Name</b></TD>
<TD WIDTH="20%"><b>Status</b></TD>
<TD WIDTH="20%"><b>Start Mode</b></TD>
</TR>
</THEAD>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD WIDTH="20%"><SPAN DATAFLD="Service Name"></SPAN></TD>
<TD WIDTH="60%"><SPAN DATAFLD="Status"></SPAN></TD>
<TD WIDTH="20%"><SPAN DATAFLD="Start Mode"></SPAN></TD>
</TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
</body>
</html>
```

And call this file services.txt

```
Service Name,Status,Start Mode
Workstation,Ok,Manual
Workstation,Ok,Manual
Workstation,Ok,Manual
Workstation,Ok,Manual
Server,Ok,Manual
Server,Ok,Manual
Server,Ok,Manual
Server,Ok,Manual
BFE,Ok,Auto
BFE,Ok,Auto
BFE,Ok,Auto
```

To your specific question it won't work on variable width fonts, vbs + notepad. If you change to a fixed width font in notepad ...

To pad at 20 fixed width characters

```
A="Running"

MsgBox A & Space(20 - Len(A)) & "|end of marker so you can see spaces in msgbox"
```

Often just putting tabs between columns will also work 95%, 100% if data is same or near same length. Again by setting larger than standard tabs in a viewer (but not notepad) can make this work. I usually use Word but if you are on 32 bit windows Edit can have custom tab widths.

Comment: I've seen commands that output content in columns in the command line before, so I know it can be done...  I have not issues with setting a fixed width font in notepad...  Think of it this way, if output is to the console and it looks right, then I can just dump that same thing to the contents of a .txt file and view it the same in notepad (if fixed width font).

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a nicely formatted text table:

```
wmic /output:Services.txt service where "DisplayName like 'CommVault%'" get DisplayName,State,StartMode
```

You can also use the various XSL files in `Windows\System32\wbem` and `Windows\System32\wbem\en-US` (or whatever language code your copy of Windows uses) to format the **wmic** output in various ways.

For example, this will give you a nicely formatted HTML table:

```
wmic /output:Services.htm service where "DisplayName like 'CommVault%'" get DisplayName,State,StartMode /format:"%windir%\System32\wbem\en-US\htable.xsl"
```

If for some reason you must use VBScript, you can simply modify the *wscript.echo* statements to output in whatever format you want, then redirect to a text file or better still make the script itself write to a text file directly.